# How do I use a statically hosted design template in a Django Project

Tags: python, css, django, templates, static

I need to use elements from a statically hosted design template in a django site. When I try using resources from the statically hosted site hosted on github pages the content is available, however when I hosted the static host on an ec2 instance (using http with Apache) the content from the design template is not available. Any thoughts on what the issue might be? Possibly using http vs https?

Ideally I would like the static content to be hosted in AWS in order to control access to it and do not want to use django's local features for rendering static content.

I tried using a statically hosted design template hosted over github pages and an ec2 instance, it works on the github pages but not the ec2 host.

I tried changing the aws security groups on the ec2 instance